# Converting rows into columns

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I want to convert rows into columns, here is my table

```
Id Total
1  50
2  50
3  150
```

Basically i want this output

```
ID 50
1  1
2  1
3  (null)
```

What ive tried so far is

```
select *
from 
(
  select id, total
  from <table>
) src
pivot
(
  //Here is where i'm stuck...what should i write here
)
```

Comment: You need to use dynamic SQL or you need to explicitly list the values to pivot on to create columns. This is a common complaint as a perceived limitation of `PIVOT`.

Answer (score 3):

Hi find the below solution

**ceate temp table**

```
select 1 as id,50 as total into #temp
union all

select 2 as id,50 as total
Union all
select 3 as id,150 as total
```

**Prepare Columns**
    declare @columns varchar(Max)

```
SELECT  @columns= COALESCE(@columns+',[','[')+cast( total as Varchar(max))+']' FROM     (select DISTINCT total from #temp) as xx

print @columns
```

**execute query**

```
EXEC ('
select *
from 
(
  select id as idd,id, total
  from #temp
) src
pivot
(
  COUNT(id) FOR total IN('+@columns+')
) as PVT
')

DROP TABLE #temp
```

you can generate any number columns with dynamically